# Hiding ViewControllers after first launch

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults

In my Application, I have a ViewController that loads up as a welcome screen. You tap "Go" then anther ViewController appears making the user create an account. when the information is submitted, their profile appears. (This is a fun test app) I want to make it so that when the user registers, uses their profile then quits the app, they don't have to keep re-registering. So I need help detecting the apps first launch, then making the WelcomeViewController and the RegisterViewController go away after first launch.

WelcomeViewController:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasLaunchedOnce"]) {

    ProfileViewController *profileVC = [[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [self presentViewController:profileVC animated:NO completion:nil];

} else {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"hasLaunchedOnce"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

     }
}
```

RegisterViewController:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasLaunchedOnce"]) {

    ProfileViewController *profileVC = [[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [self presentViewController:profileVC animated:NO completion:nil];

} else {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"hasLaunchedOnce"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

     }
 }
```

Comment: You shouldn't check if its the app's first launch. You should store in the NSUserDefaults if the user actually has created its account. He might launch your app, but still dont register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSUserDefaults is what you are looking for... store the state of the logged in user in NSUserDefaults and check/load it at the application startup...